# Loop through categories - wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a widget which simply loop five posts from a category. 
User can select the category from the widget options.

Right now I create widget and the loop with a hard coded value (Cat ID) successfully.

What I need and I'm stuck in is changing this hard coded value to dynamic select/option which pulls from the categories drop-down list so user choose from the widget options.

```html
<?php 

// Initiate roms_widget_menu ends here
   class roms_widget_menu extends WP_Widget {
   function __construct() {
       parent::__construct(
       // Base ID
       'roms_widget_menu', __('Romaisa Mege menu widget', 'roms_menu_widget_domain'), array('description' => __('Designed to display a category post in mega menu (Widgets in Menus plugin must be installed)', 'roms_menu_widget_domain'),));
   }
   public function widget($args, $instance) {
       $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
       $social_menu_title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
       // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
       echo $args['before_widget']; 
       // Romaisa Widget user front Content
       ?>
<div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-5 large-up-5">
   <?php 
      $args = array(
           'cat' => 2,
           'posts_per_page' => 5, //This is the hard coded value
       );
       $widget_module_menu_qry = new WP_Query( $args );
      
        ?>
   <?php if ( $widget_module_menu_qry->have_posts() ) : while ( $widget_module_menu_qry->have_posts() ) : $widget_module_menu_qry->the_post(); ?>
   <div class="column column-block">
      <div class="megamenu-item">
         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
         <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(230, 130)); ?>
         </a>
         <?php else: ?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(). '/romisa-assets/img/sample/230x130.png'; ?>" alt="">
         </a>
         <?php endif; ?>
         <div class="megamenu-item-typo text-left">
            <h5 class="text-left">
               <a class="megamenu-item-typo-title trans1" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></a>
            </h5>
            <p><?php echo excerpt(22); ?></p>
            <h6 class="megamenu-item-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> &nbsp;</h6>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<?php 
   // /Romaisa Widget user front Content
   echo $args['after_widget'];
   }
   // Widget Backend
   public function form($instance) {
   if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) { $title = $instance['title']; }
   else { $title = __( 'Custom HTML for Menu', 'roms_menu_widget_domain' ); }
   
   ?>
<!-- Example for widget category select dropdown that need to be dynamic -->
<select>
 <option>Category 1</option>
 <option>Category 2</option>
</select>
<?php
}
// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
$instance = array();
$instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';
return $instance;
}
} // Class roms_widget_menu ends here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code below:

```
class roms_widget_menu extends WP_Widget
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
        // Base ID
            'roms_widget_menu', __('Romaisa Mege menu widget', 'roms_menu_widget_domain'), array('description' => __('Designed to display a category post in mega menu (Widgets in Menus plugin must be installed)', 'roms_menu_widget_domain'),));
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $social_menu_title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        // Romaisa Widget user front Content
        ?>
        <div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-5 large-up-5">
            <?php
            if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            {
                echo $args['before_title'] . esc_html($title) . $args['after_title'];
            }
            $q_args = array();
            if (isset($instance['cat'])) {
                $q_args["cat"] = $instance['cat'];
            }
            $q_args['posts_per_page'] = (isset($instance['number_of_posts']) ? (int)$instance['number_of_posts'] : 5);
            $widget_module_menu_qry = new WP_Query($q_args);

            ?>
            <?php if ($widget_module_menu_qry->have_posts()) : while ($widget_module_menu_qry->have_posts()) : $widget_module_menu_qry->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="column column-block">
                    <div class="megamenu-item">
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(230, 130)); ?>
                            </a>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img
                                        src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/romisa-assets/img/sample/230x130.png'; ?>"
                                        alt="">
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="megamenu-item-typo text-left">
                            <h5 class="text-left">
                                <a class="megamenu-item-typo-title trans1"
                                   href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></a>
                            </h5>
<!--                            <p>--><?php //echo excerpt(22); ?><!--</p>-->
                            <h6 class="megamenu-item-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
                                &nbsp;</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        // /Romaisa Widget user front Content
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    // Widget Backend
    public function form($instance)
    {
        if (isset($instance['title'])) {
            $title = $instance['title'];
        } else {
            $title = __('Custom HTML for Menu', 'roms_menu_widget_domain');
        }
        if (isset($instance['cat'])) {
            $cat = $instance['cat'];
        } else {
            $cat = '';
        }
        if (isset($instance['number_of_posts'])) {
            $np = $instance['number_of_posts'];
        } else {
            $np = 5;
        }
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Title:', 'text-domain'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('title')); ?>" type="text"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('cat')); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Categories:', 'text-domain'); ?></label>
            <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('cat')); ?>"
                    name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('cat')); ?>">
                <?php
                $terms = get_terms('category', array(
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                ));
                if (count($terms) > 0) {
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('cat')); ?>").value =
                "<?php echo $cat; ?>";
        </script>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('number_of_posts')); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Number Of Posts:', 'text-domain'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('number_of_posts')); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('number_of_posts')); ?>" type="text"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr($np); ?>"/>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['number_of_posts'] = $new_instance['number_of_posts'];
        $instance['cat'] = $new_instance['cat'];
        return $instance;
    }
} // Class roms_widget_menu ends here
```